# VuGen's JSON changing content

Tags: json, loadrunner, vugen

I'm usinf VuGen for recording performance tests. I have to call some REST api to get JSON which is containing link to resource.
My code looks like this:

```
    web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=DownloadLink", "LB=downloadOriginal\":[{\"href\":\"", "RB=\"","Ordinal=ALL", LAST);
    web_custom_request("getAsset",
        "URL=SomeURL",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=0",
        "RecContentType=application/json",
        "EncType=application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Mode=HTML", LAST);
```

It is working, but part of the link is altered. This part should look like this:

```
%3A11%3A57.8192731%2B00%3A00
```

But looks like this:

```
0X1.F10A00P+559370X1.464180P+44409.5112390B000X1.32F830P+44400
```

This links has many differences because they are generated dynamically and I counldn't get the same ones for example purposes. It looks like first "%3" is changed to "0X1.F10".

I don't know what type of encoding is this. Does anybody know how decode this link or stop whole encoding?

Comment: Have you asked the developer of the app/interface about the encoding type?

Comment: No and it's not possible. This is complicated

Comment: Then you are down to reverse engineering, recording the same actions multiple times and looking for the discrete differences due to session, state and user.

Answer (score 0):

It should specify the encoding type in the response headers.

Try capturing the entire response using this:
`web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=ResponseData", "LB=", "RB=", LAST);`

Then `lr_message(lr_eval_string("{ResponseData}"));` to output the response data so you can see it in it's entirety. See if the encoding is different for all of the response or just the content. Look at the 'Content-Type'.

I also suggest adding a `web_add_header("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` at the beginning to ensure it sends with the correct encoding.